# How to find matching values in several arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, find, matching

I have N arrays of integers, each of them with unknown length.
I have to find the matching pair values in all the arrays, what is the best way to do it?
for example, given this arrays -

```
const int array_01 [8]  = {1, 8, 6, 7, 9, 1, 3, 7};
const int array_02 [11] = {3, 2, 1, 8, 2, 8, 4, 5, 9, 7, 10};
const int array_03 [10] = {4, 0, 6, 7, 7, 2, 1, 2, 2, 9};
```

the matching will be -

```
array_01, array_02 - 1, 3, 7, 8.
array_01, array_03 - 1, 6, 7.
array_02, array_03 - 1, 3.
```

Comment: Define "matching pair values".

Comment: Why isn't 8 in the `array_01, array_02` pair, and why is 6 in the `array_02, array_03` pair?

Comment: "matching pair value" means operator == on the values of the array.

Comment: I know how to implement the naive algorithm, I'm looking for something more efficient or algorithm implementation in stl\boost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can get the matching pairs for 2 arrays.

```
function match_array(array1, array2){

var match = array();

for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)

     for(int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
          if(array1[i] == array2[j]){
                match.push(array1[i]);
          }
     }

     return match;

}
```

Comment: This is too slow. Let say there are `k` arrays, all are size `n`. Your solution is O(n^2*k). Also you are going to push `1` twice when comparing `array_01` with `array_02`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to prepare a set `std::unordered_set` with the elements of one array (`O(n1)` where `n1` is the number of elements in the first array).

And then iterate through the elements of a second array, noting the ones already present in the first one (`O(n2)` where `n2` is the number of elements in the second array).

Total time complexity `O(n1 + n2)`

If you do matches with pairs of arrays, it makes no difference that you have `N` arrays to begin with.

This practical example turns both arrays into sets (it is more practical for your purposes) and then iterates:

```
std::unordered_set<int> set1, set2;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array_01)/sizeof(array_01[0]); i++)
    set1.insert(array_01[i]);

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array_02)/sizeof(array_02[0]); i++)
    set2.insert(array_02[i]);


for(auto it = set2.begin(); it != set2.end(); ++it )
    if(set1.count(*it)>0)
        std::cout << "repeated " << *it;
```

Comment: the values of the arrays will be diffrent in my actual problem so that the use of set is less likly to improve the complexity...

Comment: @idanuda the use of sets is not to make the arrays smaller, is to make lookup constant time.

Comment: @idanuda obviously, you can't solve this problem in less than that.